# Why test charge used to determine the strength of the electric field is considered positive?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-fields, charge, conventions

Why can't it be a negative or neutral test charge?

Comment: Convention. It could have been negative but you don't want half of the world following different set of rules and conventions. It's the same thing but then everything would be changed accordingly. Test charge cannot be neutral because you can't define electric field using a neutral test charge, as a neutral charge doesn't experience any force due to an external electric field.

Comment: Clearly you can't use neutral, for there would be no net force.

Comment: The choice was not important, a choice just had to be made... (not neutral though)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no evidence of prior research.

Comment: I'd argue, garyp, that textbooks for beginners aren't always very good at explaining this  definition or its motivation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either a positive or a negative charge, as long as you include its sign when substituting into the defining equation for $\vec E$, namely $$\vec E = \frac{\vec F}{q}.$$ For example, if a test charge of –2.0 nC placed at a point experienced a force of 6.0 $\mu$N South, the electric field strength at that point would be $-3.0\ \text{kN C}^{-1}$ South = $3.0\ \text{kN C}^{-1}$ North.

The point of the definition is that $\vec E$, as so defined, tells one about the environment in which one has placed the test charge, independently of the charge itself (either its magnitude or its sign)!